# OpenDJ LDAP - how to debug and view exceptions

Tags: java, ldap, opendj

I'm using OpedDJ LDAP and sometimes i get **NegativeArraySizeException(null,-1)** while doing search request!

Is there a way to view the full stackTrace when getting exceptions?
(Already enabled the logging but still no useful data is displayed!)

Is it possible to do a remote debug on OpenDJ server?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging of OpenDJ is possible and is done like any other Java based application.
You can find details on OpenDJ wiki : https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/OPENDJ/Debugging+OpenDJ+server+and+CLI

Also, you could ask the question on OpenDJ mailing list, providing details of the versions installed, the Java VM used and the command that you are using.

Finally, it's unclear to me if the exception is on the client side (in the search) or the server side.

Comment: Thanks for answering! i'll post the question in their mailing list! The exception is thrown from the server(openDJ) and received in the client!

Comment: Another question, i need opendj project source in order to debug the code but i can't fetch it anonymously from: http://opendj.forgerock.org/source-repository.html, its asking for user & password? do you know can i fetch the source?

Comment: You can access the code anonymously if you look at the trunk: https://svn.forgerock.org/opendj/trunk/opends

Comment: Hi Ludovic, we investigated the svn issue and found that it was the fact we were using SVN 1.8 instead of SVN 1.7 to check out the code